# Not able to get URL/Cookies in Ruby buts its working with Python

Tags: python, ruby, python-requests, rest-client

I am having a problem in accessing a URL via ruby but it is working with python's `requests` library.
Here is what I am doing, this link https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/derivatives?symbol=SBIN I want to access and start session with it and then need to hit link [https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-equities?symbol=SBIN'](https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-equities?symbol=SBIN%27) in the same session and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63650542/10345615) answer really helped me a lot but I need to do this in ruby. I have tried `rest-client, net/http, httparty, httpclient`, even when I am simply doing this

```
require 'rest-client'
request = RestClient.get 'https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/derivatives?symbol=SBIN'
```

It goes for infinite time with no response, I tried same thing with `headers` too but still no response for infinite time.
Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to confirm that RestClient is working for other urls, such as google.com?

```
require 'rest-client'
RestClient.get "https://www.google.com"
```

For what it's worth, I was able to make a successful get request to Google through RestClient, but not with the url you provided. However, I was able to get a response by specifying a User-Agent in the headers:

```
require 'rest-client'

RestClient.get "https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-equities?symbol=SBIN%27"
=> Hangs...

RestClient.get "https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-equities?symbol=SBIN%27", {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)"}
=> RestClient::Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized
```

I assume there is some authentication required if you want to get any useful data from the api.